# what is the best dedicated hosting provider for a file sharing site?

Tags: webserver, dedicated-hosting

What is the best place to host a file sharing site? What is dedicated linux hosting and windows hosting? What do I need to start a file sharing site?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not familiar with dedicated Linux or windows hosting, I don't think getting involved with hosting a file sharing site is ideal. There are a number of file sharing applications, clones of popular file sharing sites though not as good as the real site but have the core features. So if you're not familiar with hosting you'll probably run into problems installing an application that's database driven.